Determine where the function $f(z)$ is analytic
Consider the complex function
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+y^2)+i\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)$$
I want to see where that function is analytic to do this, let us analyze the Cauchy-Riemann equations and the continuity of the partial derivatives of $u$, $v$, note that
$$u(x, y)=\frac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+y^2) \quad \text{and} \quad v(x, y)=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)$$
So
$u_{x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\ln \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$
$u_{y}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(\ln \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$
$v_{x}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1}\left(-\frac{y}{x^2}\right)=-\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$
$v_{y}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1}\cdot \frac{1}{x}=\frac{x}{y^2+x^2}$
Clearly $u_{x}=v_{y}$ and $u_{y}=-v_{x}$ in all point except the origin. Note also, that the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are also continuous over the entire complex plane minus the origin, so it appears that the function is analytic over the entire complex plane except for zero.
But my question is, the fact that zero is neglected, comes from the fact that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not held for that point, or that the functions $u, v$ are not continuous at this point?
Thanks for your help!

Where precisely are $u$ and $v$ both defined?

All $\Bbb R^2$ except the origin I suppose, is that what makes us conclude the place where $f$ is analytic?

Look again. …….

@TedShifrin ohhh $v$ is defined in the set ${(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \neq 0 }$ ($x^2+y^2$ is allways positive with this restriction), and $\arctan$ is defined in the set ${(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \neq 0 }$, right?

You mean $\arctan(y/x)$, of course.

Right, I mean her. So I can conclude that it is analytic in the set that I have indicated?

Yes, and you shouldn’t need us to tell you that in problem after problem.

Isn't this just the complex logarithm? $z = r e^{i\theta},  \log z = \log r + i \theta$.
